# Moving from 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: windows-server-2008, 64-bit

For the first time, I am using a 64-bit OS (Windows 2008 Server R2). I want it to act as an application server and a database server. I want to know whether all the 32-bit applications, specially Visual Studio, Crystal Reports and SQL Server, work without problems in x64 OS or not. What considerations to take while migrating a 32-bit application to a 64-bit environment?

Answer (score 3):

Windows 2008 (and most other operating systems) all provide emulation for 32-bit programs on a 64-bit system.  On Windows, this is called [WOW64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241064.aspx).  This should allow most programs to be run seamlessly, but if at all possible, you may consider looking for 64-bit releases for those programs.  The emulation adds a very, very trivial amount of overhead, so running them in 64-bit mode would definitely improve performance, if only a little.

Comment: +1, WoW64 takes care of the executable's archtecture difference. The only real problems I've run into are programs written for less secure OS (particularly those written for XP and friends) choking on the security in newer OSes. As [SvenW points out](http://serverfault.com/q/335189/33417) you'll just have to test for those.

Comment: You've also got to be careful when accessing data sources with ODBC as 32bit programs are using 32bit odbc

Answer (score 0):

I never had problems running 32bit apps on 64bit OS, but there is only one general answer to this question: It depends on your particular setup and you will have to test your specific environment.